# Premake5 Won't Build On FreeBSD 10.1

Tags: lua, premake

I'm trying to build Premake5 on FreeBSD 10.1 from the sources.  I eventually got it to compile by removing the "-dl" option and using gmake explicitly for the build.  It built, but I can't get it to do anything but spit out the following error message.  Doesn't matter how I invoke it.  It crashes even on 'premake5 --help'.

Here's the message:

PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a string value)

Comment: A backtrace might be helpful here. That error means that something tried to call a string value (probably an error string) instead of a function/chunk. I'm guessing this is going to be related to loadable module support (since you removed `-dl`). (Did you mean `-dl` or `-ldl`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is buggy as all get-out.  It starts by assuming linux is posix which is clearly not the case.  They use linuxism all over the place so converting to posix is going to be quite a task, and until that is done it will never work satisfactorily on non-linux posix based systems.

The `-ldl` was obviously the first stumbling block.  The next is in the function `premake_locate_executable` in `premake.c`.  In this they are using the `/proc` filesystem which is a linuxism and since this fails on BSD they are falling back to some lua methods but they seem to be assuming that `lua_tostring` pops the corresponding value which it doesn't.  Since their stack isn't balanced in this function the following `lua_call` is trying to call the garbage they've left on the stack rather than the function they intended.

Even after I fixed this issue they use `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` to get the number of cores to multi-job the make build but they don't actually check that this call succeeds (which it doesn't outside of Linux and MacOSX).

After fixing this issue I then ran into the problem that their makefiles aren't regular make, but GNU-make, so I had to change to using `gmake` to try and build.

From that point it just came unravelled because none of the premake files in the `contrib` directory are configured for BSD despite it being one of the legal configuration targets (i.e. it doesn't default to `linux`) and so there is no configuration for those components.

**TLDR: BSD is not a supported platform**

Comment: I'm pretty sure nobody on the dev team knows much about BSD, let alone every tried it. We could do with a BSD contributor; it's got very low barrier-to-entry for contribution and hacking... ;)
Of course, we'll help out as much as we can!

Comment: @TurkeyMan BSD is basically just the Posix subset of Linux functionality.  If you strip out the Linux-isms then what you have left should run on both Linux and BSD.  Target BSD and you'll generally get Linux for free.  Opengroup holds the standards and while their website is a dog to navigate you can just google `opengroup feature` to get the cross platform documentation for it (e.g. [opengroup make](https://www.google.com/search?q=opengroup+make)).

Comment: @parakleta well done.  I think it's really important to ensure that premake is actually cross-platform on Unix rather than explicitly targeting Linux and OSX.  I mistakenly thought that if they had ported it to OSX (a BSD userspace derivative) that they would have long ago abstracted away from non POSIX specifics.  I was wrong.  I wish I had the time right now to fix that stuff.  Maybe someone could do as you suggest for a relatively simple fix (and still allow us to specify the platform build chain on POSIX).

Comment: @eris0xff Are you saying it doesn't build, or it doesn't work? OSX is sufficiently unlike Linux or BSD that it kinda requires special treatment. We have even found clang build option incompatibilities between Linux and OSX Clang. OSX has 'frameworks', and we also found -rpath differences from linux. There's quite a few OSX-specific considerations as it turns out.